# Unexpected object change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am implementing end of round function for a board game. Each players state is represented with an object that is in turn stored in array playerStates:

```
const [playerStates, setPlayerStates] = useState(getInitialPlayerStates);
    const [playerIndex, setPlayerIndex] = useState(0);

    const playerState = playerStates[playerIndex];

    function setPlayerState(playerState) {
        let tPlayerStates = [...playerStates];
        tPlayerStates.splice(playerIndex, 1, playerState);
        setPlayerStates(tPlayerStates);
    }
```

End of round function checks whether all players have finished their actions, and if so, resets global state

```
/** END OF ROUND **/
    function handleEndRound() {
        let nextPlayerIndex = playerIndex + 1 < GLOBAL_VARS.numOfPlayers ? playerIndex + 1 : 0;
        let haveAllFinished = true;
        while (playerIndex !== nextPlayerIndex) {
            if (!playerStates[nextPlayerIndex].finishedRound) {
                haveAllFinished = false;
            }
            nextPlayerIndex = nextPlayerIndex + 1 < GLOBAL_VARS.numOfPlayers ? nextPlayerIndex + 1 : 0;
        }

        if (haveAllFinished) {

            ...

            /* reset player states */
            let tPlayerStates = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < GLOBAL_VARS.numOfPlayers; i++) {
                let tPlayerState = {...playerStates[i]};
                console.log("RESETTING PLAYER STATE:");
                console.log(tPlayerState);
                tPlayerState.availableAdventurers = GLOBAL_VARS.adventurers;

                /* remove active card */
                if (tPlayerState.activeCard !== false) {
                    tPlayerState.discardDeck.push(tPlayerState.activeCard);
                    tPlayerState.activeCard = false;
                }

                /* move cards from hand to discard */
                for (let card of tPlayerState.hand) {
                    tPlayerState = addCardToDiscardDeck(card, tPlayerState);
                    tPlayerState.hand = [];
                }

                console.log("tPlayerState before:");
                console.log(tPlayerState);
                /* draw a new hand */
                for (let i = 0; i < GLOBAL_VARS.handSize; i++) {
                    if (tPlayerState.drawDeck.length === 0) {
                    console.log("tPlayerState after:");
                    console.log(tPlayerState);
                        tPlayerState = addDiscardToDrawDeck(tPlayerState);
                    }
                    if (tPlayerState.drawDeck.length > 0) {
                        tPlayerState = addCardToHand(tPlayerState.drawDeck[0], playerState);
                        tPlayerState.drawDeck.splice(0, 1);
                    }
                }            
       ...
```

The problem is that wrong player state is stored, as evidenced by the console outputs:

```
tPlayerState before: App.js:315
Object { finishedRound: true, ... color: "#FFD41A" }
```

```
tPlayerState after: App.js:320
Object { finishedRound: false, ... color: "#2A8CFF" }
```

The color identifies players, and for some reason state of the first player is exchanged by the state of the second player.

There is a lot going on with deep-nested objects and arrays and that might be the cause - however I do not see why exactly should these two outputs be different. What is the source of the change? How can I prevent it?

The complete code is hosted at https://github.com/faire2/loreHunters/.

Additional information:
The problem is pertinent to JS rather than to React. The problem was related to passing a shallow copy to of a deep object to a function. I still do not understand what exactly was going on: in the end, two strangely fused objects were being pushed by into an array even though I was pushing only one object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was passing a shallow copy of a deep nested object to a function and back. The problem was resolved by passing a Lodash deep clone of that object:

```
...
const result = addCardToHand(tPlayerState.drawDeck[0], cloneDeep(tPlayerState));
...
```

I would still like to understand what was happening, and why the two objects, both dealt with separately in a loop,  were being merged into one.

EDIT: so it seems that console.log does not always show the proper state of an object. I used "debugger" to pause the run and check for the real state of the concerned objects, which cleared all the confusion. So the problem itself was caused by a shallow copy, which was remedied by using cloneDeep from Lodash. The correct state can be checked by using the debugger;.